# Noindex, Nofollow affect "Google Custom Search" results?

Tags: robots.txt, noindex, google-programmable-search-engine

I am using Google Custom Search on my site, if I set pages to "noindex" or "nofollow", does it also affect the custom search results on my site?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Google Custom Search uses the indexed pages in Google, usually filtered for your domain. If you do not index your pages (noindex) CSE can't return them as a result.

Comment: I tried to add noindex to some pages, but one week later, I still got those page from CSE result...

Comment: There is no fixed timeset for how long it will take for existing links to be removed.